# Fatoração Prima usando Pilha

Tags: java, stack

Fiz uma pilha com vetor, com a funções básicas(push, pop, peek) e com ela quero fazer uma fatoração prima de um valor. Fiz o programa, porém quando compilo ele, fica em um loop infinito que eu não estou identificando e não retorna nada. Segue os códigos:

**Pilha:**

```
public class Pilha {

    public Object[] pilha;
    public int posicaoPilha;

    public Pilha() {
        this.posicaoPilha = -1;
        this.pilha = new Object[1000];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.posicaoPilha == -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int size() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.posicaoPilha + 1;
    }

    public Object peek() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.pilha[this.posicaoPilha];
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.pilha[this.posicaoPilha--];
    }

    public void push(Object valor) {
        if (this.posicaoPilha < this.pilha.length - 1) {
            this.pilha[++posicaoPilha] = valor;
        }
    }

    public void imprime() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Pilha vazia");
        }

        while (isEmpty() == false) {
            System.out.print(pop() + " ");                    
        }
    }
}
```

**Função Fator Primo:**

```
public class Exercicio5 {
    int fatorPrimo(int n) {
        int resultado = 1;
        Pilha pilha = new Pilha();

        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
            pilha.push(2);
        }

        for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i=+ 2) {
            while(n % i == 0) {
                n  = n / i;
                pilha.push(i);
            }
        }

        while(!pilha.isEmpty()) {
            resultado = resultado * (int)pilha.pop();
        }

        while(!pilha.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(pilha.pop() + " * ");
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

**Testa Pilha:**

```
public class TestaPilha {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Exercicio5 ex5 = new Exercicio5();

        int n = 3960;

        System.out.println(ex5.fatorPrimo(n));
    }
}
```

Obs: Fatoração prima é encontrar valores primos que são divisores de um valor `n`, que multiplicado entre si, resultam no valor de `n`, como por exemplo, 3960 = 11 * 5 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 2 * 2.

Comment: Mas o que é suposto esse seu método `fatorPrimo` retornar ? Parece que não faz muito sentido esse calculo do `resultado` que está fazendo, pois acaba por calcular o valor original que recebeu.

Comment: Você já tentou alguma técnica básica de debug, do tipo imprimir uma mensagem em cada método para ver por onde o fluxo de execução está andando? StackOverflow não é oráculo de exercícios de faculdade não...

Comment: @Isac a principio é isso mesmo

Comment: @epx vou fazer isso, obrigado

Comment: O problema principal é o `for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i=+ 2) {` que tanto o limite está mal como o incremento está `i =+2` que devia ser `i += 2`, mas tem outros problemas. Agora não posso elaborar uma resposta sem saber o que você pretende retornar no método `fatorPrimo`.

Comment: @Isac ja resolvi o problema, era esse mesmo do "i += 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta arrumar o "i =+ 2" para "i += 2"

```
    public class Exercicio5 {
            int fatorPrimo(int n) {
                int resultado = 1;
                Pilha pilha = new Pilha();

                while (n % 2 == 0) {
                    n = n / 2;
                    pilha.push(2);
            }

            for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
                while(n % i == 0) {
                    n  = n / i;
                    pilha.push(i);
                }
            }

            while(!pilha.isEmpty()) {
                resultado = resultado * (int)pilha.pop();
            }

            while(!pilha.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print(pilha.pop() + " * ");
            }

            return resultado;
        }
    }
```